# Compile java files from different folders in other separate folders

Tags: java, compilation

I know this is a duplicate, but I've already done a lot of research and still can't understand.

I have a project tree looking like that

```
.
+-- logger/
|  +-- src/
|  |   +-- logger/
|  |       +-- (*.java)
|  +-- bin/
+-- testframework/
|  +-- src/
|  |   +-- test/
|  |       +-- (*.java)
|  +-- bin/
+-- restaurant/
|  +-- src/
|  |   +-- restaurant/
|  |       +-- (*.java)
|  +-- bin/
+-- compile.sh
+-- test.sh
+-- launch.sh
+-- README.md
```

And I want compile.sh to compile everything to the right bin folders, then execute the program with launch.sh (main is in restaurant).

What I've done is

```
#!/bin/sh

LOGGER_PATH=/logger/src/logger
TEST_PATH=/testframework/src/test
RESTAURANT_PATH=/restaurant/src/restaurant

cd LOGGER_PATH
javac -d ../../bin *.java

cd ../../..
cd TEST_PATH
javac -d ../../bin *.java

cd ../../..
cd RESTAURANT_PATH
javac -d ../../bin *.java
```

But even then I don't get anything compiling, and even if it did, I have no idea if executing restaurant would make the program work.

Could you guys give me some help?
Thank you in advance.

-PS- if you have any idea for a more appropriate title, please suggest it to me :)

Comment: Do you get any errors? Or just aint compiling?